# Google Cloud API: Forbidden to access Enabled API using Service Account key

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api-python-client

I am having issues use Service Account P12 Key and getting **HttpError 403**.

However, I do not have this issue if I use Web OAuth using Client ID and Secret. However, I am creating as Service to Service application.

**Google Cloud API JSON** is enabled.

```
import os
from httplib2 import Http
from pprintpp import pprint

from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials
from apiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

SITE_ROOT = \
    os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
P12_FILE = \
    "REDACTED-0123456789.p12"

P12_PATH = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, P12_FILE)
pprint(P12_PATH)

SCOPE = \
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only'
PROJECT_NAME = \
    'mobileapptracking-insights'
BUCKET_NAME = \
    'pubsite_prod_rev_0123456789'
CLIENT_EMAIL = \
    'REDACTED-service@foo-bar-0123456789.iam.gserviceaccount.com'

private_key = None
with open(P12_PATH, "rb") as p12_fp:
  private_key = p12_fp.read()

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
    CLIENT_EMAIL,
    private_key,
    SCOPE)

http_auth = credentials.authorize(Http())

storage = build('storage', version='v1', http=http_auth)

request = storage.objects().list(bucket=BUCKET_NAME)

try:
    response = request.execute()
except HttpError as error:
    print("HttpError: %s" % str(error))
    raise
except Exception as error:
    print("%s: %s" % (error.__class__.__name__, str(error)))
    raise

print(response)
```

Error message:

```
HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/pubsite_prod_rev_0123456789/o?alt=json returned "Forbidden">
```

What do I need to do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine (I just pasted it, changed the appropriate constants, and successfully ran it).

I would double-check:

- That your client email is the correct one for the p12 key
- That the bucket you're listing is accessible to that service account

Some other things you could do to help you figure out where the problem is:

- Verify that you can list the public `uspto-pair` bucket
- `import httplib2` and set `httplib2.debuglevel = 1`, and verify that the requests that are being made are the expected ones.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I had not assigned access permissions to the service's 'client email' through the **Google Play Developers Console > Settings > USER ACCOUNTS & RIGHTS**